# Upgrade to the specific php 7.1/7.2 from php 7.0 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, php, update-manager, php7

How can I upgrade to php 7.1 from php 7.0 in ubuntu 16.04 ?

If I do a `php -v` I get this message:

```
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Why do you guys reckon Ubuntu isn't upgrading PHP to never minor versions? 7.0.8 has been superseded a few months ago.

Comment: Because even minor PHP versions break compatibility. @see hash_function in php 7.1 vs php 7

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is no official PHP 7.1 in the Ubuntu 16.04 repos.

If you want PHP 7.1, there is a version available in [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

You can install it like this:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. (optional) `sudo apt-get remove php7.0`
4. `sudo apt-get install php7.1` (from comments)

Remember that this is not an official upgrade path.  The PPA is well known, and is relatively safe to use.

*The PPA has co-installable packages (you can have multiple versions of PHP installed from that PPA).* ~[muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru)

Comment: Thank yoy @ThatGuy, you are right, but I need conditional return types "?" and can't wait to use them :)

Comment: No problems.  This should get you up and running :)

Comment: I needed to launch also: 4. sudo apt-get install php7.1

Comment: Nice, updated the answer to add your step :)

Comment: May need to do it like this:

`sudo apt-get remove php7.0` and then `sudo apt-get install php7.1`.

May have to test that further I think :)

Comment: @ThatGuy The PPA has co-installable packages (you can have multiple versions of PHP installed from that PPA).

Comment: Thanks @muru That's actually really helpful!  I've only ever installed one at a time.  I think it may be my OCD kicking in ;)  Added your note to the answer!

Comment: @ThatGuy you can write your comment as answer, just adding the php7.0 removal (if needed) and that after that any extension should be reinstalled for php 7.1

Comment: @Pherserk - There you go, added as an optional step :)

Comment: Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS hosted on EC2.

Comment: Why do 3. upgrade? If that ppa has a newer version for 7.0 it will be upgraded but what is the point when removing it seconds later? System upgrades are a nice thing to do but has are out of place when this is just about upgrading php

Comment: @redanimalwar - The PPA does not overwrite the stock PHP.  Or at least didn't at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: OK that makes my point even more valid.

Comment: @redanimalwar - I'm definitely not opposed to keeping this answer up to date.

Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: So installing 7.1 from this ppa won't provide any automatic upgrade path? I'd need to install higher versions manually?

Comment: Two questions. 1. Yes it will upgrade normally as long as you continue to use the PAPA. 2. You should be testing and installing the versions manually anyway, as part of a production server, but if you run `apt-get upgrade`, it will upgrade as a part of the routine.

Comment: If you got your PHP 7.0 from this PPA in the first place then to remove it, you need to run `sudo apt-get remove php7.0*`, not just `sudo apt-get remove php7.0` as in point 3 above.

Comment: @LukeCousins - Yes, but that is not the correct answer based on the OP's question.

Comment: This didn't work for me, i get 
`E: Unable to locate package php7.1`
`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1'`
`E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1'`

Comment: @avonnadozie repeat step 1 and 2. It looks like the PPA has not been installed, or refreshed.

Comment: Please follow this guide for more thorough guide: https://ayesh.me/Ubuntu-PHP-7.1

Comment: Unable to locate package php7.1

Comment: @DamjanPavlica - Then it sounds like the PPA didn't get added to the apt sources.  You may have to run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: @ThatGuy nope :(

Comment: @DamjanPavlica - Ok, it's out of scope for this question.  It's probably best to ask a new question and refer back to this one.

Comment: Just to note: this repo updates also to php 7.2