# How to upgrade form PHP virsion 7.x to a higher one?

Tags: php

Using phpinfo(), I have found that the installed version of PHP is 7.0.26. I want to upgrade it to PHP 7.2.

Comment: here you can find an old answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/856793/upgrade-to-the-specific-php-7-1-from-php-7-0-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the PHP 7.2 *(or any higher version 7.x)*  and remove your old version if you don't need it any more.

**First** add the PPA [ppa:ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=225&start=225), run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

**Second** install the version you need 7.2 in your case, run:

```
sudo apt install php7.2
```

**Third** if you want to remove your old existing version, run

```
sudo apt remove php7.0
```

Comment: Probably the php module for apache2 should be installed and enabled: `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.x && a2enmod php7.x`, where `x` refers to the certain version..